# All elements have same value after appending new element

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, tweepy

I am using the search_users() method of tweepy library. I want to first search the user information and then extract some required items. Finally the search result should be stored in a json file. 
The search_users api return a list of user objects. Hence, I iteratively process the user list, store the items in a user_info variable, and then use list.append().

Here is my code:

```
def Search_Users(query):
# TODO The name of the file should be modified.
f1 = open("test" + ".json", 'w')
# END TODO
res = []
user_info = {'name': None, 'screen_name': None, 'id': 0}
users = Tweeapi.search_users(q=query, per_page=20, page=10)

for user in users:
    user_info['name'] = user._json['name'].encode('utf-8')
    print user_info['name']
    user_info['screen_name'] = user._json['screen_name'].encode('utf-8')
    print user_info['screen_name']
    user_info['id_str'] = user._json['id_str'].encode('utf-8')
    print user_info['id_str']
    res.append(user_info)
    print res
json.dump(res, f1)
print "Searching finished..."
```

I was confused at the beginning because the search results appear to be same values. Then I found that each time a new element was appended to the res list, other elements also changed. Just like this:

For instance, I search "MeowKun". The result will be:
`MeowKun
leolin0720
2609369460
[{'id': 0, 'id_str': '2609369460', 'name': 'MeowKun', 'screen_name': 'leolin0720'}]
MeowKun
MeowKun
750547890
[{'id': 0, 'id_str': '750547890', 'name': 'MeowKun', 'screen_name': 'MeowKun'}, {'id': 0, 'id_str': '750547890', 'name': 'MeowKun', 'screen_name': 'MeowKun'}]
meow
MeowkunMeow
3240552107
[{'id': 0, 'id_str': '3240552107', 'name': 'meow', 'screen_name': 'MeowkunMeow'}, {'id': 0, 'id_str': '3240552107', 'name': 'meow', 'screen_name': 'MeowkunMeow'}, {'id': 0, 'id_str': '3240552107', 'name': 'meow', 'screen_name': 'MeowkunMeow'}]
Searching finished...`

Could anyone tell me the reasons resulting in this problem? And the solution please. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to python! Everything is an object, takes a bit of getting used to. `user_info` is the name for the place in memory where that object lives. If you want to store more info, you have to make a new object each time. (roughly speaking) Thus the answers below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding the data using the same starting `user_info` dict. Move the line you create it inside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, this sort of use of a list is helpful

```
 users = []    
 for user in users:
    user_info = {}
    user_info['name'] = user._json['name'].encode('utf-8')
    .
    .
    .
    users.append(user_info)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def Search_Users(query):
    # TODO The name of the file should be modified.
    f1 = open("test" + ".json", 'w')
    # END TODO
    res = []
    users = Tweeapi.search_users(q=query, per_page=20, page=10)

    for user in users:
        user_info = {} #create a new dict
        user_info['name'] = user._json['name'].encode('utf-8')
        print user_info['name']
        user_info['screen_name'] = user._json['screen_name'].encode('utf-8')
        print user_info['screen_name']
        user_info['id_str'] = user._json['id_str'].encode('utf-8')
        print user_info['id_str']
        res.append(user_info)
        print res
    json.dump(res, f1)
    print "Searching finished..."
```

you only create one `dict` in front of `for` loop. each time you put data into the `user_info`, the data are stored at the same address, and each time you append the `user_info` to `res`, actually you are appending the same object, thus, elements in `res` are the same.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Now I already solve the problem. :)